# Is there a way to set GIF RLE compress when calling Canvas.toDataUrl()?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a minimalist image creation project and I need to have the ability to create images within the browser that are uploaded and used on a server.

I've managed to create the image data for the server via calling the toDataUrl() method on my canvas object.  Specifically, I create my image by calling toDataUrl('image/gif') but the resulting image is not RLE compressed.  Is there a way that I can force the toDataUrl method to create a compressed GIF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) leaves it up to the browser on how to implement the GIF mime type. The only guaranteed MIME in the spec is `image/png`

So unfortunately, even if you're lucky enough that the browser will generate GIF, there doesn't seem to be any browsers currently that take RLE into consideration.

Comment: Thanks.  Not the answer I was hoping for, but that's what I needed to hear.